# JSON parsing data requires restart application

Tags: android, json, listview

Sorry for my poor English... here is some part of data view activity

**DataView Activity :**

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*
     * StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network
     * access on the application's main thread
     */

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    fb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb);
    name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name1);
    favo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_fav);
    contact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contact);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
    view_map = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.view_direction);

    db = new SQLController(this);

    url = getResources().getString(R.string.url);


    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    data = b.getString("itemName");

    new async_dataDetail(DataViewActivity.this).execute();

    favo.setOnClickListener(this);
    view_map.setOnClickListener(this);
    fb.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_fav:

        String myUser = name.getText().toString();
        String storedUser = db.Exist(myUser);

        // If Username exist

        if (myUser.equals(storedUser)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already exists !!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            db.adddata(context, name.getText().toString(), category
                    .getText().toString(), id, MainActivity.a);

            favoriteList = db.getFavList();

            Log.d("aaaa", name.getText().toString()
                    + category.getText().toString() + MainActivity.a);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Successfully, added to Favourities", 0).show();
        }
        break;

    }
}

class async_dataDetail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    public async_dataDetail(DataViewActivity activity) {

        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        if (MainActivity.a == 1) {

            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("777", data));

            try {

                CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("777");
            } catch (Exception e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (Favourite.a == 1) {
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("524", data));

            try {

                CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("524");
            } catch (Exception e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String response = null;

        // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters

        try {

            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(

            url,

            postParameters);

            // store the result returned by PHP script that runs
            // MySQL query

            String result = response.toString();

            // parse json data
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    st_name = " " + json_data.getString("name");
                    id = json_data.getString("id");
                    st_name1 = " Name    :   "
                            + json_data.getString("name");

                    st_contact = " Contact :  " + " "
                            + json_data.getString("contact");
                    st_category = " Category :  "
                            + json_data.getString("Category");
                    st_address = " Address :   "
                            + json_data.getString("address");

                    Log.d("favourite_data", st_name + "  " + st_contact
                            + "   " + st_category + "   " + st_address);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressdialog.dismiss();

        try {

            name.setText(st_name);
            name1.setText(st_name1);
            contact.setText(st_contact);
            category.setText(st_category);
            address.setText(st_address);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in Display!" + e.toString());

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(DataViewActivity.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Processing....");
        progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
        progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressdialog.show();

    }

}
```

**Favourite Items Activity**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fav);
    setTitle("Favorites");

    // listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView = getListView();
    db = new SQLController(this);

    favoriteList = db.getFavList();
    listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());

}

public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ViewAdapter() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return favoriteList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        nameText.setText(" Name   : "
                + favoriteList.get(position).getName());
        final TextView ageText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ageText);
        ageText.setText(favoriteList.get(position).getAge());

        final Button delete = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.removeFav(favoriteList.get(position).getId());

                favoriteList = db.getFavList();
                listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
            }
        });

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = 1;
                String aa = favoriteList.get(position).getCateg()
                        .toString();
                String bb = favoriteList.get(position).getTable()
                        .toString();
                intent.putExtra("itemName", aa + bb);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Logcat :**

```
10-16 14:41:36.700: W/System.err(23063):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
10-16 14:41:36.830: D/OpenGLRenderer(23063): Flushing caches (mode 0)
10-16 14:41:36.830: D/memalloc(23063): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x556ab000 size:6144000 offset:4608000
10-16 14:41:36.830: D/memalloc(23063): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x58d7c000 size:7680000 offset:6144000
10-16 14:41:36.830: D/memalloc(23063): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x54043000 size:4608000 offset:3072000
10-16 14:41:37.831: E/log_tag(23063): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
10-16 14:41:37.891: D/memalloc(23063): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x56291000 size:15728640 offset:15237120
10-16 14:41:37.891: D/memalloc(23063): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x594cf000 size:22794240 offset:22302720
10-16 14:41:37.901: D/memalloc(23063): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5d32e000 size:24821760 offset:24330240
```

I am getting some data in `ViewData activity` from sql data base through json.. in this activity when i press `favo` button some details is added to SQLite db and shown in list view named `favourite items activity`..
problem is that when i add some data in favourite item it is added successfully. but when i clicked on item in list view to get details of the items it is not shown it give error . but when i restart my application and click item in listview it works fine .. Every time when i add some item detail is not shown but when i restart it works fine..

Comment: the error itself tells : `type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray`. You are trying to fetch `JSONArray`  which is meant to be `JSONObject`

Comment: check what are you getting here `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);` in **result** ???

Comment: getting same error json parsing..

Comment: Show  me what you get in *`result`*

Comment: i am trying to get through log but its not giving any value its giving error  Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Please debug it and get the Value..Then only anyone can help you..

Comment: Actually show the **result** value before executing `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result); `

Comment: @SweetWisher .. i'm getting problem in debuging . problem in debugging application restarted and when it restarts it gives correct values...

Comment: comment you parsing code..and debug it :

Comment: i got solution .. thanx @SweetWisher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution after debugging, the problem was value of `Mainactivity.a` and `Favourite.a` was overlapping . so `responce` was null . but 
finally i change value `favourite.a = 1` to `MainActvity.a =2` when Favourite list item is clicked

```
if (MainActivity.a == 1) {

        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("777", data));

        try {

            CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("777");
        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if (MainActivity.a == 2) {
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("524", data));

        try {

            CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("524");
        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

now its working fine .

Comment: what is your exact requirement, explain!!

Comment: i am showing some data in dataview activity through json.. on basis of some id which i passing from main activity.. in dataview activity i am adding some data in favourite activity in istview.. but when i want detail from favourite list it doesn't show .. when i restart my app then it shows detail ...

Comment: its simple mate!  first of all remove strict mode,  make async task and in background of async task perform data loading  from server and parsing  and in post set your datat to UI. and on item click of your list, just  fetch the id and send it to new screen without finishing your current activity.